# Query regarding log in button error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page..on log in button i have a click event.But when i click on the button the page is reloaded.What might be the error.I m not able to understand. and the log in button is in form tag.
 Code for login button on aspx page:->

Code on .cs file

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string q = "SELECT * FROM Instructor WHERE EmailId='" + TextBox10.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbstring"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString() == TextBox2.Text)
            {
                Session["instructor"] = TextBox10.Text;
                Response.Redirect("InstructorHome.aspx");
            }
            else
            {  Label1. Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = "Password Incorrect";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label2. Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "Username does not Exists";
           TextBox10.Text = "";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

```html
              <h2>Log In</h2>
              <form id="LogIn" action="#">
                <div>
                  
                  <div  class="wrapper"> <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Enter Your EmaiID" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian" ></asp:Label>
                    <div class="bg">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server"  Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:TextBox> 
                  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator14" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Email ID" ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="EmailValidator" ValidationGroup="fp"  Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian"></asp:CustomValidator><br />
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator15" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Cannot Be Empty" ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="RequiredValidate" ValidationGroup="fp"  Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian"></asp:CustomValidator>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div  class="wrapper"><asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian" ></asp:Label>
                    <div class="bg">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="Password" runat="server"  Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp                  
                  <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text=""  Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian"></asp:Label>  </div>
                  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Cannot Be Empty" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="RequiredValidate" ValidationGroup="loginValidate"  Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Algerian"></asp:CustomValidator><br />
                  </div>
                  
                  
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="button" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="Login_Click"  validationgroup= "loginValidate" ></asp:Button>
  
 <asp:Button ID="Button3" class="button" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" onclick="Forgot_click" ValidationGroup="fp"></asp:Button>
              
             
              </div>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
              </form>
```

Comment: Is your question *just* why the page is reloaded? Thats expected behavior by the way...

Comment: Yes its called a post back... Why would build a website using plain asp.net anyway ?

Comment: @Priya Two major alarm bells going on with your code. SQL Injection in your sql query and most worryingly, you are storing the passwords in plain text!!!! Please read up on both and protect your users data

Answer (score 1):

Post your page_load code, I suspect you're maybe doing something here, if so wrap it in this.

```
if (!page.ispostback) {
    //your page load code here...
}
```